# Why does this functional version of QuickSort break? And how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, sorting, functional-programming, stack-overflow, quicksort

This implementation blows the stack on an array of any size:

```
function quickSort(arr){

  let pivot = arr[arr.length-1]

  return quickSort(arr.filter((num) => (num < pivot)))
    .concat(quickSort(arr.filter((num) => (num >= pivot))))
}
```

Why doesn't this work? If it can be fixed, how would I do it?

Comment: let's start with the basics: quicksort is an in-place sorting algorithm...

Comment: You’re using recursion, but what / where is your break condition?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Really? Isn't making quicksort in-place an optional optimization?

Comment: @kopasetik Could you walk me through how it will sort `[3]`, please?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that the array is already sorted, eg. `[3]`. The pivot will be `3` and the two recursions will be `[]` and `[3]`. The pivot for `[]` is `undefined`, but that doesn't keep it from filtering on greater or smaller than `undefined` which is perfectly ok since the predicate will never be tested with a zero element array. Both filters becomes `[]` and you get two recursions with `[]` from one.

```
quickSort([])           // ==> 

quickSort([])
.concat(quickSort([]))  // ==>

quickSort([])
.concat(quickSort([]))
.concat(quickSort([]))  // ==>

quickSort([])
.concat(quickSort([]))
.concat(quickSort([]))
.concat(quickSort([]))  // ==>

... (expands forever on an infinite space machine)
```

Notice I'm just expanding to first left since the right hand you will never  reach.

So quicksort doesn't sort an array that has one or less elements. In that case you have a base case that just returns the array as is.

your implementation still have a problem. Imagine sorting `[3 3 3]` you end up with `[]` and `[3 3 3]` every time. Traditionally the pivot is put in place between the two sorted arrays and not included in the last. That way you have quicksort worst case, but working solution.

About the [Quicksort is required to be in-place](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1407357&seqNum=3)

> Quicksort, as defined by Hoare in his seminal paper, is an in-place
>   algorithm. Hoare's in-place partition is his paper's main contribution
>   and a quintessential part of quicksort.